# SharePoint 2010 Claims to Classic PowerShell help

Tags: powershell, authentication, claims

I have a client requirement to move from Classic to Claims. I'm currently utilizing some PowerShell from http://derekmartin.org/archives/701

```
$webApp =
$farm = get-SPFarm
$wa = get-SPWebApplication $webApp
$site = get-SPSite $webApp
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
foreach ($user in $web.AllUsers) {
   $newuser = $user
   $newuserLoginName = “”
   write-host($user.LoginName)
   if ($newuser.LoginName.StartsWith(“i:0#.w|”))
   {
      ! $newuserLoginName = $user.LoginName.Substring(7)
   }
   $user = $newuser
   $farm.MigrateUserAccount($user.LoginName, $newuserLoginName, $false)
}
```

Unfortunately every time I try to run it I get the following

Invalid assignment expression. The left hand side of an assignment operator needs to be something that can be assigned
to like a variable or a property.
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\claims.ps1:12 char:22
+ ! $newuserLoginName = <<<< $user.LoginName.Substring(7)
+ CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidLeftHandSide

Any idea on what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Sorry forgot to paste the script in question in originally!

Comment: Umm... Could you please post the full line of the script that causes the error (you could even post the whole script if it is not too long).

Comment: Sorry that's done for you now!

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that the link was just the same with that trackback part at the end. Ok, leave me some time to see if I notice anything strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but I suppose that the exclamation mark on the

```
!$newuserLoginName = $user.LoginName.Substring(7)
```

line should just be a refuse (or at last it doesn't match any syntax I am aware of).

If you are on a test environment or are otherwise sure that you won't damage your system with a wrong comand, I would try to replace the if with:

```
if ($newuser.LoginName.StartsWith(“i:0#.w|”))
{
   $newuserLoginName = $user.LoginName.Substring(7)
}
```

The if should simply remove the "claim specific part" from the login name, so I would assume the original blog post intended it this way.

That said, know that *I have never done this before* and are only trying to spot an error in the powershell code. I don't know if that code will actually do what promised, so use that at your risk (or wait some more expert other user to confirm the behaviour).

Comment: Thanks man. Let me test this on the test environment and see what it comes back with!

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if this could be it, but since the error message points to that line and basically say "you cannot assign the value to that, I don't know what to do", I would give it a try. For what I know that line would mean "assign the value to the negation of the variable xyz", which IMHO doesn't make sense.